# writing sql query in hibernate using scrollableResults

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a dao method.

```
    public ScrollableResults getPRecord(StatelessSession statelessSession) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    Criteria crit = statelessSession.createCriteria(APRecord.class, "apr");
    crit.createAlias("mAiD", "aID", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);


    crit.addOrder( Order.asc("pName") );
    crit.addOrder( Order.asc("kNum") );
    return crit.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    }
```

This returns me duplicate results so I wrote a sql query that gets rid of duplicate results.(I have tried DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY, it doesn't work).

The sql query to avoid duplicates:

```
     select this_.pName as y0_,
     this_.kNum as y1_, 
     this_.agentG as y2_, 
     count(distinct aId1_.aID) as y3_ 
     from APS_ACCM_CurrentPatchesView this_ 
     inner join APS_ACCM_ManagedAssetsView
     aId1_ on this_. agentG = aId1_. agentG
     group by this_. pName, this_.kNum, this_.agentG
```

How do I go by writing this in Hibernate? Innerjoin is giving me a hard time.